# Codeigniter database query, or where and where combo

Tags: php, codeigniter, query-builder

I am trying to get the right combo of database entries.

Say for example, I have several events. I want all up to the ones ending today

```
$this->db->where('endDate >=', date('Y-m-d'));
```

but I also want ones that dont have a date, so they can be in the TBC

```
$this->db->or_where('startDate', null);
```

But finally I only want those where event name is bob!

```
$this->db->where('eventName', 'bob');
```

However I am getting all the eventName in the database.

How do I get only BOBs events but with those date options?

Answer (score 0):

It's all about how you place the query. You can simply try this

```
$this->db->where('eventName', 'bob');
$this->db->where('endDate >=', date('Y-m-d'));
$this->db->or_where('startDate', null);

# Syntax
WHERE eventName = 'bob' AND WHERE endDate >= 'xxxx-xx-xx' OR startDate = null

# Result
    - assume endDate is 2017-6-17
eventName       | endDate           | startDate     | Output(Gets/Not)
    Bob         |   2017-6-17       |    null       |       Gets
    Ron         |   2017-6-17       |    null       |       Not
    Bob         |   2017-6-18       |    null       |       Not
    Bob         |   2017-6-15       |    null       |       Gets
    Bob         |   2017-6-15       |    2017-3-25  |       Not
```

Comment: Thanks, I tried this one, but I get all the eventName in return. I have tried every possible combination and I am stumped. It should work like that but I get **eventName** with **bill** too

Comment: Hi, I eventually found a solution. I am going to post an answer.

Answer (score 0):

You can simply use like this

```
$this->db->where('endDate >=', date('Y-m-d'))->or_where('startDate', null);
$this->db->where('eventName', 'bob');
```

Comment: I tried this one, and it simply ignores the 
`$this->db->where('eventName', 'bob');` I thought this would work to, I get all the eventNames back :(

Answer (score 0):

Thanks to Abdulla and Muhammad, I have found a solution. I did this that seemed to work (after trying all possible combinations)

```
        $this->db->where('eventName', 'bob');
        $this->db->where('startDate', NULL)->or_where('endDate >=', date('Y-m-d'));
        $this->db->where('eventName', 'bob');
```

So I top and tailed it. I know its not DRY but meh, its the only thing that works. Weird. And I have less than 15 points so cant give them a vote.

Answer (score 0):

You can try as below:

```
$this->db->where(" (end_date >= '".date('Y-m-d')."' OR start_date = '' ) AND eventName = 'bob' ");
```